# android - app crashes after setting Autofocus and Face Detection in Camera API

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, face-detection, autofocus

I tried to set *Autofocus* and *Face Detection* like this in `onResume()`, but my app crashes (it doesn't like the lines with `startFaceDetection()` and `camera.autofocus(...)` - app doesn't crash when they're commented). Here's the code.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open(0);
    setPreviewSize(FULL_SCREEN);
    camera.setFaceDetectionListener(new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
            Log.i("FACES:", Integer.toString(faces.length));
        }
    });
    camera.startFaceDetection();
    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            Log.i("AUTOFOCUS", "AutoFocus: " +
                    (success ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));
        }
    });
}
```

How to rewrite it that it work properly and not crash?

Comment: where is crash stacktrace?

Comment: @pelotasplus it says "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid face detection type=0". No idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late but I guess you are writing the same code more than once, so you just need to call:

```
camera.setFaceDetectionListener(facedetection callback object);
camera.startFaceDetection();
```

and

`camera.autoFocus(auto focus call back arguement)`.

comment me if you want to know anything else.
Thanx.